# Store fields in an array and display in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query which fetch all distinct row. i want to store it to an array and display it back using for each loop. can anyone help me. thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
//PREPARE QUERIES
//distinct effective dates
$allsched = $this->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT effective_date,status,in_use FROM `working_sched` WHERE `emp_id` = ? ");
$allsched->bind_param('i', $emp_id);
$allsched->execute();
$allsched->bind_result($distinctdate,$stat,$in_use);
$allsched->store_result();
$numrows = $allsched->num_rows;

//check if query turned empty!
if($numrows == 0){
    echo '<div id="error">Sorry no Working Schedule to be displayed for <b><i></i></b></div>';  
}else{
//if query returned TRUE
$effdatedist = array();
while($allsched->fetch()){
        $effdatedist[] =  $distinctdate; //store the effective dates in an array
        $effdatedist['stat'] = $stat;
}
$allsched->close();
}
```

and in my foreach loop i want to display the following

```
foreach($effdatedist as $a){
    //display here
    date, status, in_use
}
```

Comment: what kind of array format you want to achieve? `$allsched->fetch()` is already returning an array value.

Comment: i want to store the returned values in an array to use it for another query.

Comment: i want to store the returned values of $allsched->fetch() in an array then display it the foreach loop. but unfortunately i dont know how to store it in the array and how to display it :(

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to add this to your while loop:

```
while($result = $allsched->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  array_push($effdatedist, $result);
}
```

Where fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set. So your values can then be printed with something like this

```
foreach($effdatedis as $row){
  echo "Date: "   . $row["effective_date"];
  echo "Status: " . $row["status"];
  echo "In Use: " . $row["in_use"];
}
```

If this isn't the type of array that you want returned by the fetch() method then take a look at the php manual page below for a list of all of your options:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: im not using PDO Api im using MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process them one at a time (which is almost always true), then you don't need to get them all and put them into memory first - this does bad things when you have thousands of records, and gives you no benefit at all. You are reading them in, one at a time, and putting them in an array; then you are reading the array, one at a time, in the exact order you put them in, and handling them.

Instead, consider putting the `//display here` code that you currently have in your `foreach` loop, straight into the `while` loop. This will work fine, even if you are querying inside the loop. You may also consider modifying your query so you get all the data in one go, rather than fetching a subset of the data, and then fetching the rest one-query-per-row.

Also, I've just realised you haven't asked a question - you probably want to fix that before it gets closed :)

Comment: That's ok, we all start here on our first post. That's why I warned you. I wouldn't close it, but I've seen some closes where I think it should have been left open.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($effdatedist[] = $allsched->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

hope it helps