# print_r redundencie (index and key value)

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

after my PDO query

```
$reponse=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM coordonnees WHERE id=9); 
$data=$reponse->fetch()
```

I print_r the $data

And I have something like

```
[id] => 70
[0] => 70
[nom] => Nom
[1] => Nom
[rue] => rue de Joie, 144
[2] => rue de Joie, 144
[numero] => 
[3] => 
[bte] => 
[4] => 
[codep] => 5000
[5] => 5000
[ville] => Namur
[6] => Namur
[pays] => Belgique
[7] => Belgique
[email] => xxxxt@xxxx.net
[8] => xxxx@xxxx.net
[tel] => 0xxx/42.48.72
[9] => 0xxx/42.48.72
```

So, everything is in double because of the index. What is the reason and how to avoid this in order to get

```
[id] => 70
[nom] => Nom
[rue] => rue de Joie, 144
[numero] => 
[bte] => 
[codep] => 5000
[ville] => Namur
[pays] => Belgique
[email] => xxxxt@xxxx.net
[tel] => 0xxx/42.48.72
```

Thank you so much !

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

That is supposed to happen with a default `->fetch()`

However you can tailor the output you require by using a parameter

To get an Associative array returned do

```
$reponse=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM coordonnees WHERE id=9"); 
----------------------------------------------------------^
$data=$reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or if you want a object returned

```
$reponse=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM coordonnees WHERE id=9"); 
$data=$reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

> See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for all the possibilities

Comment: @RichardHousham Now and again a bit of low hanging fruit can be quite tasty

Comment: Sorry - just lmao!

Comment: @RichardHousham I looked for a dup as I assumed there had to be one, but I cannot find one with a good answer, can you?

Comment: Mmm, nothing concrete - this is close ish.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869955/store-fields-in-an-array-and-display-in-php/21870124#21870124 but even then not really

Answer (score 0):

read the doc!
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Its the fetch style,

```
PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set
```

Is the default

```
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set
```

Is what you need so in code

```
$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM coordonnees WHERE id=9);
$data=$reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Heck it's even in the examples in the document!